# Pictures of products not showing up when doing the deploiement on the server from the local

Tags: magento2, product-images

when trying to do the deploiment on the server of my website, the pictures of products were not showing up so what i have to do to show them on server as local thanks in advance

Comment: Have you uploaded them to the server? It's impossible to find out without more details about your deployment.

Comment: so how and where to put them on the server exactly ? and if they are on the server I am supposed to choose the picture of each product again from the new path ?

Comment: Put them into the same path as on the old server (i.e. pub/media/catalog/product/). You don't have to reassign them if the database content is the same.